# scope of vector element in c++ stl

Tags: c++, stl

for the follwoing program segment:

```
std::vector<int*> v;
{
    int a=5000;
    int *aa =&a;
    vv.push_back(aa);
    cout<<"\n"<<*(v[0]);
}
cout<<"\n"<<*(v[0]);
```

output:

```
5000
5000
```

---

my doubt here if inserting pointer to an vector ,vector  should have address and while acessing it from outside of local block it should not print the elemet becuase "a" has local scope.
here oject of that pointer has local scope still its accessible from outside of the scope.
plese help.
thanks

Comment: It's undefined behavior

Comment: Accessing a stale pointer. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/1782465).

Comment: "Stale pointer". I like this expression.

Comment: pro tip: don't use naked raw pointers, especially in C++, you have all the tools that you need to avoid them and express a better semantic, you also get smart pointers in the event that you really really really need one of those things .

Comment: C++ is not a managed language.  Don't expect the compiler or the run-time to recognize whether a pointer is still valid.  That's the coder's job.

Comment: `it should not print the elemet because ...`  So what do  you think *is* supposed to happen when this occurs?  If you don't know, then that's the point of "undefined behavior".  No one can guarantee what should happen, even the language can't guarantee what happens.

Answer (score 5):

The vector grabs a copy of the pointer, it is perfectly valid to use it.

The problem is **with the address where the pointer points**: you're accessing out-of-scope stack memory which could have been recycled (i.e. *used*). You have no guarantee on this access and thus invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: thats true , thanks.. one more doubt

Comment: std::vector<int> v;
{
    int a=5000;
   
    vv.push_back(a);
    cout<<"\n"<<v[0];
}
cout<<"\n"<<v[0];
output:

5000
5000  :: here when pusing the element to vector is it creating a new elment then adding to vector list or its pointing to same elment on the stack if later on is true then  above one is also undefined behavior.?

Comment: nope, that is fine. It's copying the element in the vector.

Comment: It is not valid to use a pointer that does not point to someplace valid. That is, you have a problem even before you dereference. Technically.